# Ember app can't find assets

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember 2.6.1 to build a web application and am trying to use a custom image file in my stylesheet.

In the Ember-cli documentation, it states:

> To add images, fonts, or other assets, place them in the public/assets directory. For example, if you place logo.png in public/assets/images, you can reference it in templates with assets/images/logo.png or in stylesheets with url('/assets/images/logo.png').

I tried to follow these instructions exactly.. My image file is located in the public/assets/images directory, and it's called plus.png.

In my less stylesheet, I reference url('/assets/image/plus.png'), but I always receive a 404 Not Found error:

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/img/plus.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I've tried every possible url resource path I can think of...what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check http://localhost:8080/assets/image/plus.png

Comment: Might be because Ember CLI fingerprints the images. But I believe the less stylesheet should be updated with the fingerprint value. For your case though, it's not. Do you compile less separately or built-in with Ember CLI?